# How to change hint text font size and color in j2me using LWUIT?

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I am using the following code in java file and not using resource file.

m_txtSearch = new TextField();
m_txtSearch.setHint("Search");

Then how can i change the font size and color of hint text ?

Can u please help me ?

Answer (score -1):

```
Font font = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 12);
txt.setFont(font);
txt.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
```